# Create an image using terminal

Tags: image, image-processing, terminal, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

How would I create and populate the RGBA of an image using stored raw data instead of random data in terminal?

I create random pixel png image using the below code

```
mx=200;my=200;head -c "$((3*mx*my))" /dev/urandom | convert -depth 8 -size "${mx}x${my}" RGB:- randoms.png
```

Comment: What do you mean by "using stored raw data" is it a raw data file? What is `convert`, Is it ImageMagick? In case you are using ImageMagick, please add *imagemagick* tag.

Comment: @Rotem Yes, raw data file. Okay i have added the tag.

Comment: Try: `convert -size 200x200 -depth 8 RGBA:raw_data_file_name[1] img.png`, were `raw_data_file_name` is the raw data file (assuming your "raw data" comes from a file). The `[1]` is used for converting only the first 200*200*4 bytes of the file. The result is going to be random in case "raw data" file contains random data...

Comment: @Rotem it prints out this error convert: unexpected end-of-file 'f.stl': No such file or directory @ error/rgb.c/ReadRGBImage/247.
convert: no images defined `img.png' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3273.

Comment: **1.** Make sure that the size of the input file is 160000 bytes or above. If file is smaller, use `-size 100x100` or `-size 10x10`... **2.** In case it still gives you an error, try updating ImageMagick. For new versions the syntax is `magick -size 200x200 -depth 8 RGBA:raw_data_file_name[1] img.png`